# The Diagnostic Service Host failed to start due to the following error

Tags: windows-7, windows-event-log, windows-service

I am receiving the following error in my System event log:

Service Control Manager, Event ID 7000

> The Diagnostic Service Host failed to start due to the following error:
>   A privilege that the service requires to function properly does not exist in the service account configuration. You may use the Service Microsoft Management Console (MMC) snap-in (services.msc) and the Local Security Settings MMC snap-in (secpol.msc) to view the service configuration and the account configuration.

After a bit of searching around, I've found other users that have this problem have solved it by editing their Local/Group Policy and change their

`Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Profile system performance` entry to have `Administrators,NT Service\WdiServiceHost` as the value.

I've also added `LOCAL SERVICE` as some have suggested, but that does not solve the problem either.

Performing a "sc query WdiServiceHost" command results in:

```
SERVICE_NAME      : WdiServiceHost
TYPE              : 20 WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS
STATE             : 1 STOPPED
WIN32_EXIT_CODE   : 0 (0X0)
SERVICE_EXIT_CODE : 0 (0X0)
CHECKPOINT        : 0X0
WAIT_HINT         : 0X0
```

Not sure why its related, but some responses are asking to make sure the `Diagnostic Policy Service` is started, which mine is. `Diagnostic System Host` is started as well.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried reconfiguring the service to run under the local Administrator account (instead of LocalSystem) to see if it starts under that user?

Comment: It did not fix the issue, but it did change the error to "The account specified for this service is different from the account specified for other services running in the same process."